# How can I reinstall bluetooth drivers in Windows 10?

Tags: bluetooth, windows-10, drivers

I have an Asus ROG Maximus IX Code motherboard. It has Bluetooth 4.1 baked into it, and it was working great until recently. I can't be sure exactly what caused this, but at some point recently, bluetooth stopped working. I went to go toggle bluetooth back on and noticed that the toggle switch is missing. https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPHND.png

1. I have booted into my BIOS and confirmed that bluetooth hardware functionality is enabled.
2. I simply ran the bluetooth troubleshooter. It thinks that "Bluetooth is not available on this device". https://i.stack.imgur.com/s08oF.png
3. I had to manually reconfigure my Bluetooth Support service to automatically start up with Windows, since it had been completely disabled (not sure how it got disabled). It is now started and configured correctly. https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SzLi.png.
4. Multiple times it was suggested on the windows forums to simply uninstall all bluetooth drivers and restart Windows, and that this would prompt Windows to correctly reinstall the drivers. I navigated to the device manager, but found that all of my bluetooth drivers had been hidden. Navigating to `View > Show hidden devices` revealed them. I uninstalled them and restarted Windows, but it did not reinstall those drivers. Now when I view my drivers in the Device Manager (making sure to reveal hidden devices) there are no bluetooth drivers at all https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qQ9M.png
5. I've made sure that I have no pending Windows updates https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFA70.png
6. I've run the DISM tool to check for any corruptions in my Windows installation. There are currently no issues. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eeif5.png
7. I downloaded and installed the bluetooth device driver directly from my [mobo manufacturer website](https://rog.asus.com/motherboards/rog-maximus/rog-maximus-ix-code-model/helpdesk_download/). There is a driver clearly marked "Bluetooth". I ran the included installation wizard, which when finished, prompted a restart. When Windows rebooted, Bluetooth still did not work. Although it had installed a new directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\Bluetooth Suite`, when I view my Device Manager, there are still no bluetooth drivers to be found.
8. I've tried installing [this generic Intel bluetooth driver](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/30061/Intel-Wireless-Bluetooth-for-Windows-10). The results were nearly identical to point 6. Still no bluetooth drivers are shown in my Device Manager.
9. I've circled back around and made sure that the bluetooth service is still enabled, and I re-ran the bluetooth troubleshooter. The troubleshooter still thinks that "Bluetooth is not available on this device"

This is all really frustrating, but at this point I'm just wondering why, If Windows doesn't want to reinstall its own bluetooth driver, why won't it let me manually install any either? I've probably tried running the install wizards for bluetooth drivers 4 times now. I've even tried multiple versions that are provided by my mobo manufacturer. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Wrong site, I'm afraid. You're looking for [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions, not general computer or OS support. You can find more information about this site in the [help].

Comment: @Ken Yup, my mistake. Looks like this question's already been moved to superuser.

Comment: I have this exact same problem. just started at same time frame as well.